# Leaking TarInfo objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, tar, objgraph

I have a Python utility that goes over a `tar.xz` file and processes each of the individual files. This is a 15MB compressed file, with 740MB of uncompressed data.

On one specific server with very limited memory, the program crashes because it runs out of memory. I used [objgraph](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objgraph) to see which objects are created. It turns out that the `TarInfo` instances are not being released. The main loop is similar to this:

```
with tarfile.open(...) as tar:
    while True:
        next = tar.next()
        stream = tar.extractfile(next)
        process_stream()
        iter+=1
        if not iter%1000:
            objgraph.show_growth(limit=10)
```

The output is very consistent:

```
TarInfo     2040     +1000
TarInfo     3040     +1000
TarInfo     4040     +1000
TarInfo     5040     +1000
TarInfo     6040     +1000
TarInfo     7040     +1000
TarInfo     8040     +1000
TarInfo     9040     +1000
TarInfo    10040     +1000
TarInfo    11040     +1000
TarInfo    12040     +1000
```

this goes on until all 30,000 files are processed.

Just to make sure, I've commented out the lines creating the stream and processing it. The memory usage remained the same - TarInfo instances are leaked.

I'm using Python 3.4.1, and this behavior is consistent on Ubuntu, OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is actually by design. The `TarFile` object maintains a list of all the `TarInfo` objects it contains in a `members` attribute. Each time you call [`next`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d0f8f242531b/Lib/tarfile.py#l2236), the `TarInfo` object it extracts from the archive is added to the list:

```
def next(self):
    """Return the next member of the archive as a TarInfo object, when
       TarFile is opened for reading. Return None if there is no more
       available.
    """
    self._check("ra")
    if self.firstmember is not None:
        m = self.firstmember
        self.firstmember = None
        return m

    # Read the next block.
    self.fileobj.seek(self.offset)
    tarinfo = None
    ... <snip>

    if tarinfo is not None:
        self.members.append(tarinfo)  # <-- the TarInfo instance is added to members
```

The `members` list will just keep growing as you extract more items. This enables usage of the [`getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getmembers) and [`getmember`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getmember) methods, but is just a nuisance for your use-case. It seems the best workaround is to just keep clearing the `members` attribute as you iterate (as suggested [here](http://blogs.it.ox.ac.uk/inapickle/2011/06/20/high-memory-usage-when-using-pythons-tarfile-module/)):

```
with tarfile.open(...) as tar:
    while True:
        next = tar.next()
        stream = tar.extractfile(next)
        process_stream()
        iter+=1
        tar.members = []  # Clear members list
        if not iter%1000:
            objgraph.show_growth(limit=10)
```